# ActiveRecord find Parent if ALL Children respect a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

`availables_locales` is a postgres Array which contains a list of locales. What I'm, trying to do is get all Room that EVERY of its children `boxes` respect the condition. (contains the locale)

This is what I got, but it only acts as, at least one, not every.

```
class Room 
  has_many :boxes

  scope :available, -> { joins(:boxes).where('boxes.available_locales @> ?', "{#{I18n.locale}}") }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If any Room has at least one Box, try inverse condition like:

```
class Box < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room

  scope :not_locale_rooms do
    select(:room_id)
      .where.not('boxes.available_locales @> ?', "{#{I18n.locale}}")
  end
end

class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :boxes

  scope :with_all_locale_boxes, ->{ where.not(id: Box.not_locale_rooms) }
end
```

Otherwise you have to add one more `where` to `with_all_locale_boxes` to ensure Room has a boxes.